How to receive parameters from HTTP POST request in AWS lambda API function overcoming CORS error?
I have created AWS lambda function for API request in python.
Client send API post request to lambda function using ajax with several parameters.
But I can't get those parameters in lambda function.
The error is Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://xxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/default/sssss' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
I have defined CORS policy in AWS lambda configuration.
Here is the AWS lambda function.
def lambda_handler(event, context):
if event['httpMethod'] == 'OPTIONS' or event['httpMethod'] == 'POST':
    source = json.loads(event['body'])
        
    response = {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',  # Set CORS to allow requests from any origin
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token,X-Requested-With',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS',
        },
        'body': json.dumps(f'{source['dias']}')
    }
else:
    response = {
        'statusCode': 404,  # Example status code for other methods
        'body': json.dumps({'message': 'Method not allowed'})
    }

return response

I have researched about this error.
They say that I need to add http statusok to response, but I can't find exact code sample with lambda python code.

source = json.loads(event['body']) - what do you expect that to result in - for an OPTIONS request that does not have a body? Likely either this, or the attempt to send this non-existing data later on, 'body': json.dumps(f'{source['dias']}'), will cause your script to error on OPTIONS requests.

That's not how cors works. The browser is refusing to connect to the lambda because the server at http://127.0.0.1:5000 didn't set a cors policy to allow connections to amazonaws.com. Try returning your webpage along with the header Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * to troubleshoot, but do not use this in prod.
